# Layout broken on Firefox mobile on Android

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

When the site loads, it looks normal, but there's a white stripe to the right of it which I can horizontally scroll over, or zoom like on the screenshot:

> [image: screenshot with white bar]

This has been the case for as long as I've been using the mobile site.